# How to add existing nodes/contents to a book page?

Tags: nodes

This is my scenario:

> I have several nodes of different content types in my drupal site. I want to create a book page and add these existing contents to book page as child pages rather then creating child pages.

Already looked at **[Outline designer](https://www.drupal.org/project/outline_designer)** and **[Book made simple](https://www.drupal.org/project/book_made_simple)  module**, but i think none of these modules has this functionality. Is there any module available for that or i need to build a custom module?